# python: get objects imported from __all__ variable

Tags: python, python-import

Contents of `module.py`:

```
__all__ = ["A", "B"]


class A(object):
    ATTRIBUTE = 'a'


class B(object):
    ATTRIBUTE = 'b'
```

My goal is to import this module and create the following dict: `{'a': A, 'b': B}`, mapping the `ATTRIBUTE` of each class to the class itself. The catch is that I don't know the names of the classes, so I cannot simply do: `from module import A, B`. However, I do know that all the classes I want should be stored in the `__all__` variable.

I tried the following code, which works, but it looks ugly, I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to get my expected output?

Contents of `main.py`:

```
import module
from module import __all__ as module_all


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {}
    for obj_str in module_all:
        obj = eval("module.{}".format(obj_str))
        data[obj.ATTRIBUTE] = obj
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'a': <class 'module.A'>, 'b': <class 'module.B'>}
```

Comment: `{cls.ATTRIBUTE: cls for cls in map(lambda n: getattr(module, n), module.__all__)}`…